# Change value of html table column, generated in MySQL query, using php

Tags: php, mysql, dom

So, I have a table, that resulted from a MySQL query. this query is an inner join of two tables from a MySQL DB, in which one provides a product name, and the other a price table in HTML (which can have 2 or more columns, and variable number of rows).

Mysql query:

```
SELECT catalog_product_entity_varchar.value as `name`, catalog_product_entity_text.value as `html_table` from catalog_product_entity_varchar INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_text on catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id=catalog_product_entity_text.entity_id AND catalog_product_entity_text.attribute_id=171 AND catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id=71"
```

To output the table, I used the following:

```
echo '<table border="1">';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo
            '<th>'.$row["name"]. '</th><tr><td>'. $row["html_table"].'</td></tr>';

    }
```

Now, I need to change the content in the "html_table" part, specifically, from the second row (first is text) of the second column (first is text also).

I've looked into several parsers like simplehtmldom or DOM class of php, but I still can't grasp how to just change those specific rows/columns.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 steps :

- Add JQuery code which will send request to a PHP file and get response. After getting it will be loading that JSON and show in table->tbody section.
- PHP file will receive request and then connect with MySQLi and fetch results as per your requirements and return JSON.

Comment: Ok, i can try that, haven't done that yet. My main goal is to build a small PHP script, so I'd like to avoid mixing jQuery and JSON, and so on. This will be used in some magento stores which use those html tables instead of the proper magento options. With this info, do you think there is another way i can do that?

Comment: Well that you can do in 2 ways, with and without page refresh. If you go with page refresh then you can save offset in hidden field or in session and every page refresh define a button when we click it will fetch next few records. If we go without page refresh, like load more option then we need to JSON and JQuery

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is add a conditional to your while loop to skip the table headers, and some kind of formatting function.

```
echo '<table border="1">';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

//This boolean flag will determine if the row is the header (first row), 
//and skip formatting for this row
$header_row = true;

//We can use a closure here to do our custom formatting. 
//If you have another formatting method elsewhere, 
//use that instead of this.
$format_html_table = function($data) {

    //manipulate $data here based on what you need to do for formatting 
    //for all of the non-header rows
    //ex: $data = ...
return $data;
};

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($header_row) {
        $html_table = $row["html_table"];
    } else {
        $html_table = $format_html_table($row["html_table"]);
    }
    echo
        '<th>'.$row["name"]. '</th><tr><td>'. $html_table.'</td></tr>';

    //We set the boolean flag to false here after the first row has processed, 
    //so all remaining rows will be formatted.
    $header_row = false;
}
```

---

There really is no reason to mess with dom parsers for this. You can simply perform your edits on the raw source data response from the database before any markup is generated at all.